# Jenkins vstest runner - no files matching the pattern

Tags: jenkins, visual-studio-2019, vstest.console.exe

I am new to Jenkins and trying to run some unit test for a sql database using VS Test Runner plugin each time I am getting the response "no files matching the pattern [full file path]/Unit_tests.dll".

I have tried running the tests in command line by running:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" [full file path]/Unit_tests.dll
```

and this executes the tests successfully. I am passing the same arguments I am passing into the jenkins plugins which returns "no files matching the pattern" message?

can anyone advise what I am doing wrong or need to do to get it to work

Answer (score 0):

It seems work after set the vstestrunner path with double quote and execution name.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).